# Adding a rule with "specific header" in outlook 2015 mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, rules

I am upgrading from outlook 2011 to 2015 on a mac, with el Capitan. There doesn't appear to be any way to move all of my rules, so I'm re-generating them. I only have 5-10, so it's not a big deal.

However, one of my rules has:
Specific Header: Message-ID does not contain pull

On 2011, this works fine.

On 2015, I have the "Specific Header" option, and then it gives a text box for the header, and then a pulldown for "does not contain", but then there's no text box for "pull"

Has anyone else seen this?

2011:
[image: 2011 version]

2015:
[image: 2015 version]

Comment: I just noticed that one was "does not contain" and the other is "contains" but they work the same.

Comment: Huh? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Where you stated in your comment that `I just noticed that one was "does not contain" and the other is "contains" but they work the same.`. I thought that meant you actually found where the field for your rule was found where it needed to specify `contains` that you previously "thought" was missing and that's why you asked the question in the first place.  I guess I didn't realize that you were missing some "pull" field but I found your MS post where the MS people asked you to open a bug ticket for the issue, correct?

Comment: I tried re-installing, and it didn't help...

And yeah, the problem is that the text box at the end isn't present...

Current status: reverted to 2011.

Answer (score 3):

Thought you'd like to know they fixed this in a recent version (15.36). 
If you're unable to update for some reason, I think you are still able to tab through the fields and edit it there without being able to see the field.

[image: Specific header rules working in v15.36]

Answer (score 2):

At some point they seem to have "solved" this problem by removing the "specific header" option and replacing it with the "header" option. So you can't check if a specific header has "pull" but you can check if ANY header has "pull" which seems sub-optimal...